# WPF Converter Enum to Array

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

I'm developing a WPF project and I need to fill in a combobox with the values present in an enumeration.

I want to do it by implementing this double conversion (have a look to the code that follows). I've been able to implement in one direction looking at internet examples, but I couldn't solve the reverse direction.

My exact purpose is clarified by my answer to @BenRobinson: *The ComboBox is bound to the enum, and to a property which holds the SelectedItem and is called OpenedResultFilter. I want that when I change this property value, the combobox updates the selected item. Sorry for the confusion.. I'm not very skilled with WPF..*

Can you help me?

```
<ComboBox 
MinWidth="80" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EnumTypeToEnumArrayConverter}, ConverterParameter='Goldbet.GoldbetBackOffice.WPF.Model.ResultValidation.StagingOpenResultValidationFilter, Goldbet.GoldbetBackOffice.WPF.Model', Mode=OneWay}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding OpenedResultFilter, Mode=TwoWay}" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left"
Margin="1,2,1,2" 
DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>


<UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <Converters:BoolNullableToBoolConverter x:Key="BoolNullableToBoolConverter" />
            <Converters:EnumTypeToEnumArrayConverter x:Key="EnumTypeToEnumArrayConverter"/>



public class StagingResultsBatchImportViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel, IHierarchyViewModel
    {
private StagingOpenResultValidationFilter _openedResultFilter = StagingOpenResultValidationFilter.Tutti;
        public StagingOpenResultValidationFilter OpenedResultFilter
        {
            get { return _openedResultFilter; }
            set
            {
                if (_openedResultFilter != value)
                {
                    _openedResultFilter = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("OpenedResultFilter");
                }
            }
        }
}


public class EnumTypeToEnumArrayConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Type enumType = Type.GetType((string)parameter);
        return Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<int>().Select(p => Enum.ToObject(enumType, p));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: In what way would you convert back from a collection to an enum? You can't programatically add values to an enum, it is fixed.

Comment: Please share the xaml or the code where you are trying to do so

Comment: Is this MVVM or not? Because this isn't a good way of populating ddls if it is.

Comment: @CBauer: yes, it's MVVM, I'm about to add also the XAML to the example

Comment: @BenRobinson: The ComboBox is bound to the enum, and to a property which holds the SelectedItem and is called OpenedResultFilter. I want that when I change this property value, the combobox updates the selected item. Sorry for the confusion.. I'm not very skilled with WPF..

Comment: @Revious - Why do you need to convert back?

Comment: @CBauer: The ComboBox is bound to the enum, and to a property which holds the SelectedItem and is called OpenedResultFilter. I want that when I change this property value, the combobox updates the selected item.

Comment: You can "convert back" an int to the enum value just by casting, `int a = 1` `SomeEnum MyEmun = (SomeEnum)a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using MVVM as I suspect you could do something like this, it displays all the Enum values in a the ComboBox named enumCombo in the XAML:

```
public enum myEnum
{
    One,
    Two,
    Four,
    Eight
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private IEnumerable<string> _enumValues;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _enumValues = ConvertEnumToStrings<myEnum>();

        enumCombo.ItemsSource = _enumValues;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> ConvertEnumToStrings<T>()
    {
        var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
            .Cast<T>()
            .Select(x => x.ToString())
            .OrderBy(x => x)
            .ToArray();

        return enumValues;
    }
}
```

If you are doing MVVM this enum conversion would be done in the ViewModel and exposed either as a string collection (like above) or as ViewModel encapsulating the value (of the enum) and a friendly name for the enum value, i.e. name-value pair which has the ability to user friendly in the UI.

Comment: I don't know why someone down voted this answer because although it might not be technically accurate for the question author, it is still a far better solution that using an `IValueConverter`. +1 to level the field.

Comment: It got downvoted because OP asked for how to convert BACK from strings, not TO the strings. Edit: it wasn't me, I just know why someone would

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I made a lot of mess by opening this question.

The actual problem was completely different, so, if the question adds no value to the community feel free to vote to close or delete it.

Comment: If you don't think the actual answer to this question is going to be useful for someone at some point in the future you should delete the question. Otherwise post the answer and accept it, maybe someone else will find value in it.

Comment: Accepted. I think it can be useful, even only to realize that the problem was not in lack of conversion. If someone is at my same level he could learn something new from that answer!